# Is there a way to overcome DSRA9010E "'setReadOnly' is not supported on the WebSphere" exception?

Tags: spring, oracle, transactions, websphere

our application is using Spring for TX management and is marking certain transactions as readonly. When deploying our application on websphere (8.5.5.3) with a Oracle JDBC Connection we are getting exceptions like the following:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: DSRA9010E: 'setReadOnly' is not supported on the WebSphere java.sql.Connection implementation.
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalOracleDataStoreHelper.setReadOnly(InternalOracleDataStoreHelper.java:371)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.setReadOnly(WSJdbcConnection.java:3646)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.getTargetConnection(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:410)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy476.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:239)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy476.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
```

I know what websphere is trying to tell me but I was wondering if there is a way to disable this check so that Connection.setReadonly calls are just ignored instead of throwing an exception.

Of course I could also change the application to not use readonly transactions but that would be much more complicated.

Comment: This looks like a Websphere bug to me; has it been reported yet?

Comment: Not by myself. I've also not tested it with newer websphere versions like 8.5.5.5. We ended up in removing the readonly transaction demarcation from our spring application context files.

Comment: +1 to remove the read only demarcation, as Kai answered. It's easier than unwrap the connection. Anyway, Gas' answer is very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to unwrap the `connection` object like this:

```
Context ic = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ic.lookup("jdbc/OracleDS");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

if (conn.isWrapperFor(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class)) {
     // Returns an object that implements the given interface to
     // allow access to non-standard methods, or standard methods
     // not exposed by the proxy.
     oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection oraCon = conn.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class);
     // Do some Oracle-specific work here.
     oraCon.setReadOnly(readOnly);
     ....

}
conn.close();
```

See [WebSphere Application Server and the JDBC 4.0 Wrapper Pattern](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21577331)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle JDBC (12c onwards; perhaps 11g as well?) can be tricky to use with readonly -
according to https://marschall.github.io/2017/01/28/oracle-read-only.html:

> Calling Connection.setReadOnly(true) with the 12c driver no longer establishes a read only transaction

This means that Spring (before version 4.3.7) also struggles to set read only transactions with Oracle JDBC (see previous link).

To overcome this, you need to manually include `SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY` in your SQL, instead of relying on Spring's `@Transactional(readOnly=true)`.

However, from Spring 4.3.7, the transaction now acts correctly, and so you should no longer see this issue (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19774)